# Nginx Load Balancing

Tags: image, nginx, redirect, proxy, load-balancing

I want to load balance my website with nginx.

The load balancing in nginx wiki is proxy, so the actual file being downloaded from the frontend server. (http://wiki.nginx.org/LoadBalanceExample)

This is how I need the balancing:

user request file:

- http:// site.com/image1.jpg

nginx redirect user to one of the servers (with Location header):

- http:// s1.site.com/image1.jpg
- http:// s1.site.com/image1.jpg
- http:// s3.site.com/image1.jpg

Is this possible with nginx?

Comment: This possible, but quite useless. Instead of loading the image from server, you add an additional redirect and hit the server again. What you need to do is do use the static domains (sx.site.com) directly in your html. (e.g.: `<img src="http://sx.site.com/image1.jpg`)

Comment: can you still give an example on how to do that? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http {
  split_clients "${remote_addr}" $server_id {
    33.3% 1;
    33.3% 2;
    33.4% 3;
  }

  server {
    location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
      return 301 "${scheme}://s${server_id}.site.com${request_uri}";
    }
  }
```